# extract netezza table records to linux local file system

Tags: netezza

Would like to extract Netezza table data to local box ? So is there any native adapter or tools available ( Like TPT in Teradata)  which can be implemented and extract records from Netezza ? If not what would be the best solution to do so. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the ‘create external table as select ... from ...’ syntax. It has a ODBC or JDBC possibility that should make this possible.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/t_load_unloading_data_remote_client_sys.html

Comment: Thanks Lars. I have tried the netezza external table with JDBC driver and able to extract to local environment.

Comment: Good to know. Please mark the postong as ‘answered’ so otters can see that it works.... glad that I could help